# Add custom image to Eclipse SWT

Tags: java, image, url, eclipse-plugin, swt

How can I add custom image to Eclipse SWT, I tried use ImageDescriptor. But I probably do something wrong.

```
private Action stopAction;
stopAction.setText("Stop");
        stopAction.setToolTipText("Stop running");


        stopAction.setImageDescriptor(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().
                getImageDescriptor(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJS_INFO_TSK));

        ImageDescriptor imgDesc = null;
        try {
            imgDesc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(new URL("icons/stop.png"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stopAction.setImageDescriptor(imgDesc);
```

Comment: Do you get an exception? What is the result? And what is the desired outcome?

Comment: @Baz exception was this: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: icons/stop.png
desired outcome was get custom image to button
so use instead of this stopAction.setImageDescriptor(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().
                getImageDescriptor(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJS_INFO_TSK));
I use the code below to load custom image which is in forlder in same project in icons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To load the image descriptor from a file in the plugin use:

```
final URL fullPathString = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("icons/stop.png"), null);

ImageDescriptor imgDesc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(fullPathString);
```

where `bundle` is your plugin bundle, get this from your Activator or:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");
```

Don't forget to add your `icons` folder to the `build.properties` file so that it is included in the built plugin.

Comment: Thx, but what is the plugin id?? Can't I get it by some method call?

Comment: It is the id you define in your MANIFEST.MF for your plugin. In the MANIFEST.MF/plugin.xml editor it is the ID field on the overview page.